# polyglossia hebrew as a secondary language for title and author

Tags: polyglossia, hebrew

I'm trying to set hebrew as a secondary language with polyglossia.
I wish that the title, author and date would be in hebrew and the rest would be defaulted to english.
This is how my document is set-up currently:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}

\begin{hebrew}
\title{כותרת}
\author{מחבר}
\end{hebrew}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\section{test}

\end{document}
```

And this is what is showing up:
[image]
I've tried to look on how to begin writing in a secondary language using polyglossia and I've found someone using `\begin{language}` and `\end{language}` blocks so I've wrapped my title and author commands with it, but as you can see nothing is showing up.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two main problems:

1. It does not use a Hebrew supporting script - you should change from `Arial` to `David CLM`
2. The `otherlanguage` environment is used to typeset several paragraphs in Hebrew and is not intended to be used outside the body of the document. Meaning it should be used after `\begin {document}`

If you remove that environment and wrap the `maketitle` with it, then it works.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLMl}

\title{כותרת}
\author{מחבר}

\begin{document}

\begin{hebrew}
\maketitle
\end{hebrew}

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\section{test}

\end{document}
```

Remember to use XeLaTeX.

Notice that once `\maketitle` is in a Hebrew environment then all the title is in Hebrew including the date. If you wish ONLY the title and author to be in Hebrew you can use `\texthebrew{}` as @Davisior stated:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLMl}

\title{\texthebrew{כותרת}}
\author{\texthebrew{מחבר}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\section{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\title{\texthebrew{כותרת}}` should also work.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this just fine in LuaLaTeX with `babel` (using version 7.00 of Arial, not the one from the ’90s available for Linux).

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[english,bidi=basic,layout=sectioning]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{hebrew}

\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures={Common,Discretionary,TeX}]{Arial}

\title{כותרת}
\author{מחבר}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\section{test}

\end{document}
```

[image: Arial sample]

You could add `\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Mitiam CLM}` or your font of choice, and `babel` will switch to it whenever you type in Hebrew.  With this version, `babel` will switch to `Script=Hebrew` and `Language=Hebrew` whenever it sees Hebrew.

You can also add `\babeltags{english=english}` and `\babeltags{hebrew=hebrew}` to be able to overwrite the auto-detection and use `\texthebrew` or `\begin{english}`.  This will not properly format full paragraphs in Hebrew as right-to-left unless you turn off auto-detection and use language tagging all the time, however.

Comment: Could you explain why I should use babel over polyglossia as I'm not sure I understand

Comment: @Jorayen It’s not so much that you should as that you *can*: someone else already posted a solution with `polyglossia`, so I followed up with the alternative approach.

Comment: @Jorayen However, there are at least two things you can only do with `babel`: auto-detect the language you’re typing in, with no tagging in the source, and supporting PDFTeX.

Comment: I see, well that sound convenience.
But why did you said `using version 7.00 of Arial, not the one from the ’90s available for Linux` ?

Comment: @Jorayen I don't believe the older version of the font supports Hebrew.

Comment: Amazing that this could be done with `Babel`.
However, `polyglossia` seems to handle long paragraphs much better.

Any advise for fixing this in `Babel`?

Comment: @Benben Contrary to what I said in the post, `\begin{english}` and `\begin{hebrew}` won’t work well in Babel. What you actually want to do is `\begin{otherlanguage}{english}` and `\begin{otherlanguage}{hebrew}` ... `\end{otherlanguage}` to correctly change between RTL and LTR paragraphs and titles.